# Twitter GET friends/lost API limitaion

Tags: twitter

In the case of standard plan, more than 15 times `GET friends/list` fetching isn’t be allowed within 15min. How can I increase this limit?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increase the limit - but you can increase how many results are returned.

According to [the documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-list.html), normally you will only get 20 results per API call.  You can increase this to up to **200** by using the `count` parameter.

For example, `friends/list.json?screen_name=edent&count=200` will get you the first 200 of my friends. You can then use the `cursor` to get more.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But if users who has more than 3,000(200 * 15) follows can't get datas. Do you know some good ideas to realize?

Comment: You can't change the limits. But if you wait after your 15 minutes, you can start again from where you left off.